# ASP:Checkbox Bind Issues

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a MSsql Database and trying to bind a checkbox to one of the fields.  The field in the DB is a Bit so it is looking for a 1 or 0, but the asp:checkbox deals with Boolean values.  How do I go about doing this binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the value returned from the database is of type int, then user Convert.ToBoolean

Answer (score 0):

0 is false and 1 is true, if that helps.

Otherwise - what ORM are you using? It should surface `bit` columns as .NET `bool` properties.